# Read pcap through scapy and fetching a specific value

Tags: python, scapy

[image: wireshark_data]

```
    pcapFile=rdpcap(pcap)
    for pkt in pcapFile:
        try:
            if pkt[IP].src=='198.18.32.1' and pkt[IP].dst=='198.18.50.97' and pkt[IP].len>=400:

                data= pkt[Raw].load

(Pdb) pkt[Raw]
<Raw  load='\x00\xab\x0b(\x00\x00\x01\xdf\xab(\x05\x04\x03\x05\x00\x00\x00S\x03\x0020181014T121200.0000000....
```

in wireshark bit followed for  00 ab 0b is 28 but what i get from scapy is a (.How to get the value 28 from scapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem I solved my problem with this :

```
print str(packet).encode("HEX")
```

Comment: The correct answer would be to use `bytes(pkt)[28]`